# Changed after checked - Angular [selected]

Tags: angular, select, foreach, inotifypropertychanged, checked

I'm using material chips for tags in Angular, which are looped by *ngFor.

```
<mat-chip class="c-pointer" *ngFor="let popularTag of popularTags; let i=index" [selected]="popularTag.is_user_tag" (click)="toggleTag(i)">#{{ popularTag.title }}</mat-chip>
```

I need, to toggle 'is_user_tag' value on chip click, but it throws the error

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'mat-chip-selected: true'. Current value: 'mat-chip-selected: false'
```

I tried setTimeout() and ChangeDetectorRef methods, but none of them solved the problem.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try to split up the html-code where the onClick is in the mat-chip component? My guess is that the current location of the onClick is 1 level too high, i.e. it clicks on the whole list instead of the item.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem occurs when you have more than one selected chip. If you want multiselect, you have to set `[multiple]="true"` on `mat-chip-list`

```
<mat-chip-list [multiple]="true">
    <mat-chip class="c-pointer" *ngFor="let popularTag of popularTags; let i=index" [selected]="popularTag.is_user_tag" (click)="toggleTag(i)">#{{ popularTag.title }}</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x7tkwc

Comment: Don't copy and paste from the comment "multitple" won't work haha (Lazy, I'm aware)